# how to take last element from Map<String,Integer>

Tags: java

Hi I have a MAP which gives all records after counting elements. In this record set last element of MAP is the final output of counted records for me .. but how to fetch it and assign it to String ( to use  it for later purpose)?

```
Map<String, Integer> stringsWithCount = new TreeMap<String,Integer>();
                        for (Message msg : convInfo.messages) {
                            // where ever your input comes from: turn it into lower case,
                            // so that "ccc" and "CCC" go for the same counter
                            String item = msg.userName;
                            if (stringsWithCount.containsKey(item)) {
                                stringsWithCount.put(item, stringsWithCount.get(item) + 1);
                            } else {
                                stringsWithCount.put(item, 1);
                            }
                        }
```

I am travesing the map like below

```
for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : stringsWithCount.entrySet()) {      

  System.out.println(entry.getKey()+"("+entry.getValue()+")");
                        }
```

Now its printing

```
G_LO(1)
FCHAN95(1)
G_LO(1)
FCHAN95(2)
G_LO(1)
FCHAN95(2)
G_LO(1)
WVU(1)
FCHAN95(2)
G_LO(1)
SWONG00(1)
WVU(1)
FCHAN95(3)
G_LO(1)
SWONG00(1)
WVU(1)
FCHAN95(4)
G_LO(1)
SWONG00(1)
WVU(1)
FCHAN95(5)
G_LO(1)
SWONG00(1)
WVU(1)
FCHAN95(6)
G_LO(1)
SWONG00(1)
WVU(1)
```

here starting from last unique records I want to access --> FCHAN95(6) G_LO(1) SWONG00(1) WVU(1)

Comment: Please clarify your question. What is your problem and desire output?

Comment: as stated in question I want to access the last elements which have the final counts means  FCHAN95(6) G_LO(1) SWONG00(1) WVU(1) should be fetched to one string. I dont want all elements of MAP

Comment: a `Map` doesn't have *the last element*

Comment: You want to keep the type of the `Map` as `TreeMap` then you can access the methods of TreeMap such as [TreeMap#lastEntry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#lastEntry--)

Comment: after keeping map as TreeMap I am getting half result G_LO=1
G_LO=1
G_LO=1
WVU=1
WVU=1
WVU=1
WVU=1
WVU=1
WVU=1   not fully processed final result last entry

Answer (score 2):

As treemap has built in method like below

```
String lastKey=((TreeMap<String, Integer>) stringsWithCount).lastKey(); // for last key
Integer lastRecord =((TreeMap<String, Integer>) stringsWithCount).get(lastKey) // for last record
```

//stringsWithCount  is your map variable

Comment: It is declared as a Map. Without casting you cannot access lastKey. Also, for last entry, you can call .lastEntry

Comment: String lastKey=((TreeMap<String, Integer>) stringsWithCount) .lastKey();

Comment: after casting its printing "1"